# Can I create a branch of python? How would I go about doing that?

Tags: compiler-construction

Python is a generally simple, and easy-to-understand language both in syntax and logic. I'm thinking of a project in which I would need a slightly modified version of Python with little logic, and syntax tweaks.

I have the idea to branch Python and to add the changes, save, and be done. Thus I have two questions: Can I branch Python to add modifications to it? And how would I go about doing that?

Comment: "Can I branch Python to add modifications to it?" - yeah, why not? It's open source software. How **exactly** to do that depends on what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. The source code of Python language is open source and available here: https://github.com/python/cpython

Python is written in C language and knowledge to write and compile C code is needed to modify the Python language.

Remember to read their licence and follow the rules.